# Tabulator - Programmatically set focus and assign a value to a specific cell

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using tabulator.js which every time a user edit a cell (`cellEdited:function`) it calls a function to store the specific value to db and after that it refreshes (reload) the entire table.

What i'm willing to do is to keep both row and column index into a variable before save. After tabulator refreshes, will apply cell focus at the specific cell was before.

Is there any function to directly access cell's value? like `tableName.setValue(rowId, ColId, value);`

my typical table setup is:

```
function setup_table(dataset){

table = new Tabulator(document.getElementById("qc_table"), {data:dataset,layout:"fitColumns",addRowPos:"bottom",index:"ID",
     keybindings:{"navNext" :'tab("9")'},
             
columns:[{title: "ID", field: "ID", headerSort:false, width: 80}, 
         {title: "title1", field: "f1",width: 80,editor:"input"},
         {title: "title2", field: "f2",width: 80,editor:"input"},
         {title: "title3", field: "f3",width: 80,editor:"input"}],

  
         cellEdited:function(cell){
    
         // -- HERE GET ROW INDEX AND COLUMN INDEX BEFORE SAVE-- 
         
         // SAVE TABLE TO DB
         saveTable().then(function(done){
         
         // CODE TO REFRESH TABLE
         
         // -- HERE APPLY FOCUS TO THE PREVIOUS EDITED CELL --
         });
  
         }
 });
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There should be no need to refresh the table, you can simply call the ***setValue*** function on the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/components#component-cell) passed into the `cellEdited` callback.

```js
cellEdited:function(cell){
    // SAVE TABLE TO DB
    saveTable().then(function(done){
        cell.setValue("whatever value you want")
    });
}
```